# facebook client window using python gui

Tags: wxpython, facebook

I have posted this ques with in wxpython tag, but thought of posting it here as need desperate help on this. We have been trying to build an app for facebook client sort of thing. We would like to display the fb status updates/post updates on client native machine. Just for the ref: something like this http://loiclemeur.com/english/2009/03/facebook-client-minor-upgrade-turn-sound-onoff.html. We have used wxPython for our all other gui part for this application. But for continuous update one, I am just not having any clue what would be the best approach for this. I guess I am missing something big time on this front. Any pointers/help/suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0):

With wxPython, I would use a wx.Timer object to check Facebook periodically for updates. I'm pretty sure you can't hit them too often or your application's API key will be revoked. Make sure you know the limits of your key. Anyway, in the timer objects handler, I would update your application's GUI with the new updates.